# Boot receiver broadcast adb command is not working in Android Oreo 8.1.0 Go Edition device?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I am  working on an app which has not actvity and will be in preloaded mode in Android Oreo Go devices.When i,m installing app on Oreo Go non rooted device and invoking boot receiver using command **adb shell am broadcast -a `<`package name`>`intent.BOOT_COMPLETED -n `<`package name`>`/.OnBootReceiver** app is not receiving boot receiver while same app with same adb command is working fine on Android Oreo devices.

Is there anyway to invoke boot receiver in Android Oreo Go device?

Thanks

Comment: did you find solution ?

Comment: Not yet...still looking for solution.

Comment: you can try this https://github.com/devggaurav/BroadcastReceiver-For-Naught-and-Oreo-devices